# Most efficient way to loop through '...'

Tags: r

I'm developing a package in R which main interface is two classes: a class handling data (let's call it Data) and a class handling a collection of Data instances (we call it Collection). Data instances can be rather larger (50 mb +), which is why the Collection class is a wrapper around an environment.

I want to implement a `c()` function for Data which will result in a Collection instance. In order to do so the arguments are passed as `...` and the Collection instance has to be build up iteratively. I know I can loop through `...` by first making it a list by `list(...)`, but this could be potentially expensive. Is there anyway to loop through `...` without first copying everything over to a temporary list?

Comment: what type of your Data instances made of ? If there are vector-based, they are not actually copied when passed to a function or to a new list, so it is not expensive.

Comment: It contains other S4 instances. The biggest of these are made of Data frames and lists...

Comment: Do you use a Reference class for Collection ? If so you could also use ref class for Data...

Comment: Not really. Bioconductor, which is where this is hosted, prefers S4, so this is an S4 with a slot containing an environment. In essence the same effect. Implementing Data in the same way is certainly a possibility, but the main question is still interesting I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What seems to work is to use the `dots` function from the [pryr package](https://github.com/hadley/pryr) (I can imagine there are other more simple solutions possible):

```
library(pryr)

fun1 <- function(...) {
  l <- dots(...)
  result <- list(mode="list", length = length(l))
  for (i in seq_along(l)) {
    v <- l[[i]]
    result[[i]] <- eval(v)
  }
   result
}
```

Timing this against an implementation using `list` and an implementation without `...`

```
fun2 <- function(...) {
  l <- list(...)
  result <- list(mode="list", length = length(l))
  for (i in seq_along(l)) {
    v <- l[[i]]
    result[[i]] <- v
  }
  result
}

fun1 <- function(...) {
  l <- dots(...)
  result <- list(mode="list", length = length(l))
  for (i in seq_along(l)) {
    v <- l[[i]]
    result[[i]] <- eval(v)
  }
  result
}

fun3 <- function(a, b) {
  list(a, b)
}

> system.time(r1 <- fun1(large_object1, large_object2))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.060   0.072   0.133 
> system.time(r2 <- fun2(large_object1, large_object2))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.132   0.132   0.265 
> system.time(r3 <- fun3(large_object1, large_object2))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.056   0.076   0.132
```

We see that the implementation using `dots` performs similar as the implementation without `...` and faster than the implementation using `list`.

If you don't want to depend on `pryr`: the code of `dots` is quite 'simple':

```
dots <- function (...) {
  eval(substitute(alist(...)))
}
```

Comment: @KarlForner Well, not directly `alist(...)` returns a one element list with `...` as its value...so...well...ehm... I can't say I completely understand `dots`:(

Comment: If the function is for a package, use `eval.parent()` in `result[[i]] <- eval(v)`. Otherwise it might search the wrong namespace...